# can't change default values adding to ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I put in some values to ListView. I do it in MainWindow() method, and later. Although later added data can be changed, the values I put in the MainWindow() method cannot be changed
the main window class I work loads data from xml file and enters to ObservationCollection

```
ObservableCollection<MonitorData> monitorList = new ObservableCollection<MonitorData>();

    public ObservableCollection<MonitorData> MonitorList
    {
        get
        {
            return monitorList;
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {

        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"/monitor.xml"))
        {
            string name = string.Empty;
            string address = string.Empty;
            string type = string.Empty;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    switch (reader.Name.ToString())
                    {
                        case "name":
                            name = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                            break;
                        case "address":
                            address = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                            break;
                        case "type":
                            type = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                            monitorList.Add(new MonitorData() { Name = name, Address = address, Type = type });
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

the xaml - there I try to present data from xml file

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Monitor" x:Class="Monitor.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="1332.047" Width="810">

<Window.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView Margin="5" x:Name="MonitoringListView" ItemsSource="{Binding MonitorList}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Address" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Address}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Type" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Availability" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Enabled}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

class I work with

```
public class MonitorData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

I add data every 10 seconds and try to change it,
it is possible to change data I added in Timer_Tick, but somehow fail to change the data I entered in the MainWindow() from xml file

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        monitorList.Add(new MonitorData() { Name = "new", Address = "111", Type = "sometype", Enabled = true });
        for (int i = 0; i < monitorList.Count; i++)
        {

            monitorList[i].Name = "new name";
            monitorList[i].Enabled = true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Impliment [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316417/2470362) Interface

Answer (score 0):

MonitorData class should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface if you want updates to show.